# How to return array of elements from a void function in another c file

Tags: c, arrays, function, void, element

How to return array of elements from a void function in another c file. My assignment is to reverse the array in lab8.c and then use main.c to show the results I have no idea how to reverse the elements or print the results in main. Functions outside of my main cannot use printf or scanf

main.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include "lab8.h"

int main(void) {

    int x[100];
    int y[100];
    int n = 0;
    int count, i, product;


    printf("Enter the length of both arrays\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    printf("Enter the %i elements of the first array\n", count);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    scanf("%i", &x[i]);
    }


    printf("Enter the %i elements of the second array\n", count);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    scanf("%i", &y[i]);
    }


    product = inner_product(x, y, count);
    printf("Inner product of first array and second: %i\n", product);

    printf("Enter the %i elements of the array\n", count);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    scanf("%i", &n[i]);
    }

    reverse(n, count);
    printf("Reverse of array 1: %i\n", n);


    return(0);
}
```

lab8.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include "lab8.h"

int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int count){

    int i;
    int result = 0;

    for( i=0; i<count; i++){
        result = result + (a[i] * b[i]);



    }

    return result;
}

void reverse(int a[], int count){

    int i, r, end = count - 1;


    for(i=0; i<count/2; i++)
    r = a[i];
    a[i] = a[end];
    a[end] = r;

    end--;

}
```

Comment: When an answer is helpful you can accept it by clicking the check mark, you need to read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you want to use this site properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one mistake in your code, the `for` loop in the `reverse()` function has no braces and hence it's just executing `r = a[i]` `count / 2` times.

```
void reverse(int a[], int count) {
    int i, r, end = count - 1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < count / 2 ; i++) {
        r      = a[i];
        a[i]   = a[end];
        a[end] = r;
        end--;
    }
}
```

and to print the result in `main()` just

```
reverse(x, count);
printf("Reverse of array 1: %i\n", n);
for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    printf("%d ", x[i]);
printf("\n");
```

also, do not ignore the return value of `scanf()` if it doesn't succeed at reading the values your program will invoke *UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR*, you should learn good practices right from the beginning.

Comment: when I done this I got the following errors  main.c: In function âmainâ:
main.c:32:16: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
main.c:35:2: warning: passing argument 1 of âreverseâ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
lab8.h:6:13: note: expected âint *â but argument is of type âintâ
main.c:38:17: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: @CodyHutto yes because I've just noticed that `n` is not an array? why are you passing `n`? It has to be `x` or `y`, I've updated the answer, check it.

Comment: thanks that works but it returns the reverse but also where     printf("Reverse of first array: %i\n", x[i]); it returns a long number

Comment: @CodyHutto I told you not to ignore `scanf()`'s value, that has to be because some value is uninitialized, did you read the tour?

Comment: yes I did so what you are saying is my `scanf("%i", &x[i]);`  has a uninitialized value?

Comment: i changed `printf("Reverse of array 1: %i\n", n);` to `printf("Reverse of first array: ");` and it works perfectly now